# Can't Separate by Parts to Scatter Objects

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out the best way to scatter a bunch of objects around randomly on a surface.  I don't want to use particles because I want the objects to interact with each other (collide, lay on top of one another, not overlap, etc).

My method I want to try is thus:

1. Create very low poly sphere roughly the size of the object I want to use in my animation
2. Add rigid body dynamics to said object
3. Array the object in multiple directions (32 x X, 32 x Y, 32 x Z, total: 37k low poly spheres)
4. Apply the Arrays
5. Separate the parts
6. Bake the dynamics
7. Replace the object data so that the more complicated object replaces the low-poly objects used for the above simulation

[image]

However I'm stuck on step 5. Blender just hangs, won't finish trying to separate the parts. My 32-core Threadripper should be able to crush this. I do similar simulations like this all the time in Cinema 4D and there is very little lag.

Would love a second opinion on my solution

[Project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jcssm21pey50u8/Rigid%20Body%20Why.blend)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the "cheap" way with

1. add icosphere
2. press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> , <kbd>2</kbd>
3. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> as often as you need
4. Select all icospheres, repeat steps 2 + 3 (but with x/z coordinate)
5. and then i would continue with your step 6

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/gF-jCY53uAE

Comment: Hey Chris, that's a definite workaround from working with Arrays to achieve the same result, and actually I'm glad you mentioned it because my computer hangs just the same, once I try and add Rigid body tags to all of the objects.  I guess I'm just trying to do something that Blender just can't do.  In C4D this would be a snap.  I've heard that Houdini is geared toward this kind of complicated dynamic system as well.  Bummer, but it's good to know!  Cheers ;)